# How flutter call Widget repeatedly?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have Data List. And I want to use my Widget repeatedly as much List.length. So, I used to using for loop. But it doesn't work as expect. Widgets are displaying the last data. Here's my code. please check this. Thank you.

The variables are temporary thing. And the Data is List of Json.

Scaffold

```
return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) ...[
              Charts(GetData: Data[i]),
            ],
          ],
        ),
      ]),
    );
```

and this is initState() in Charts

```
initState() {
    data1 = widget.GetData.data1;
    data2 = widget.GetData.data2;
    data3 = widget.GetData.data3;
  }
```

Comment: `children: [ for (int i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) Charts(GetData: Data[i]) ],`

Comment: @pskink I think he should try using a `StreamBuilder` instead of a for loop

Comment: i think you can use StreamBuilder or flutter_bloc

Comment: But i want to know if the Data is static or is it changing continuously?

Comment: Niether. Data is just Json instances List.

Comment: Then just use a map or a `ListView.builder`

Comment: Wait I'm writing an answer for you on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `ListView.builder` for this:

```
 ListView.builder(
                itemCount: Data.length,   //you just need to specify the amount of items
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Charts(GetData: Data[i]); //and then this line will return Data.length amount of Charts in that ListView.
                },
              ),
```